# How is being born on Nag Panchami beneficial?

Tags: scripture, astrology, birth

I was born on Nag Panchami. Being a Narcissist, I wanted to know the advantages one gets if born in Nag Panchami. What do the scriptures or astrology maintain on this?

Comment: https://hindupad.com/child-born-on-panchami-tithi-effects-impact/ might be helpful...

Comment: Every person is born on some date. If timings are taken into consideration, there are many differences. So, every one asks a question on the advantages of their birth day and birth minute, there can be 100 questions daily. These details are found in one's horoscope (kundali). So, the best way is to make a chart with an expert astrologer. btw, I don't understand the scripture tag. We should not tag if there is a word scripture in the question. Someone might have said that to you, but that is a wrong way to do.

Comment: This board is not even able to gather 10 questions per day and you are talking about theoretical possiblity of getting 100 questions per day? Keep dreaming. And questions avalanche isn't a problem as long as questions are within scope. And I wanted if something written on this in any scripture or not. Period.

Comment: You should use a @ before a name to reply. If someone asks a question like this with a variation of tithis and dates and hours, what about ten, we would get hundreds of them. Because there are 30 days and 24 hours. Every person's horoscope is different. And mind while you write comments. No one's dreaming here. I don't see any scripture quoted in the answer you received. Is that site a scripture or something else? No one posts a personal advice in the answer. You will know that if you read related [meta-tag:faq]. I know you ain't got time for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Naga Panchami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naga_Panchami) falls on the Sukla Paksha (the bright phase of moon) Panchami Tithi of the Shravana month.

So, we need to check the effects of getting born on the bright phase of moon as well as that of getting born on the Panchami Tithi.

Quoting from [Astrojyoti.com](http://www.astrojyoti.com/effects-and-results-of-birth-in-tithis-and-weekdays.htm):

> 459 – 461. Results of Fortnights: Now stated are effects of births in
>   the two fortnights.
>
> (a) Bright Lunar Half: According to Yavanas, **one born in bright
>   lunar half (Sukla Paksha) will be long-lived and will have sons. He
>   will protect many people, be charitable, friendly, honourable, and
>   dominated by his spouse.**
>
> (b) Dark Lunar Half: One born in or dark lunar half (Krishna Paksha)
>   will be indolent, unclean, and jealous. He will blame others, will
>   speak a villager’s language and will disregard all religions.

And, the effects of getting born on Panchami Tithi are given in the following verses:

> 465. Chaturthi: One born on Chaturthi (fourth lunar day) will be miserly, of tale-bearing disposition, fierce, adventurous, heroic,
>        fickle-minded and crafty.
> 466. **Panchami: One born on Panchami (fifth lunar day) will be honourable, long-lived, highly intelligent, stable minded, truthful
>        and winner of senses, i.e. an ascetic.**

The astrological text that the website is actually quoting from is [Hora Ratnam by Bala Bhadra.](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/hora-ratnam-two-vols-4699197688.html)

So, overall, from the perspective of Tithi and Paksha, it is a good day for getting born. But Tithi is only one of the five limbs (Panchangas) that shape a native's features with the other four being Vara (weekday), Nakshatra, Yoga and Karana. This has to be taken into account too.

Comment: Yeah but dominated by spouse does not look good to me.. hope you'll be able to tackle it by virtue of some of the other features present in ur horoscope :D @Rohit.